# Can't get my insensitive user login function to work, what am I doing wrong? Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a loginfunction connected to my database, but I can't get it to work as I get an error when I type a username with a big letter ("M") if I registered with a small letter ("m").

yourEmail, yourPassword, usernameEntry, passwordEntry = entry in my xaml file

Registercode:

```
var userInfo = await parseAPI.signupUser (yourEmail.Text, yourPassword.Text);

if (userInfo ["error"] == null) {
    Application.Current.Properties ["userId"] = userInfo ["objectId"].ToString ();
    Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"] = userInfo ["sessionToken"].ToString ();
    await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync ();
} else {

}
```

and my logincode:

```
var userInfo = await parseAPI.loginUser (usernameEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text);

if (userInfo ["error"] == null) {
    Application.Current.Properties ["userId"] = userInfo ["objectId"].ToString ();
    Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"] = userInfo ["sessionToken"].ToString ();
    await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync ();

    //loginstrings
    String theUserString = usernameEntry.Text.ToUpper ();
    String theUserString = passwordEntry.Text.ToUpper ();

    //registerstrings

    String theUserStringRegister = yourPassword.Text.ToUpper ();
    String theUserStringRegister = yourEmail.Text.ToUpper ();

    Navigation.PopModalAsync ();

} else {
    await DisplayAlert ("Wrong password", "Try again", "Ok");
}
```

Comment: You are logging in, and then `ToUpper()`ing the strings. Why? Neither your `signupUser` nor your `loginUser` specifies anything about case insensitivity

Comment: In addition to @Rob's question, does the login code above even compile? It looks like 'theUserString' and 'theUserStringRegister' are declared twice.

Comment: yes it works, but only if i use the same registeredinfo. so if i register "m" i have to type "m" when i login and not "M".

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the user's input directly to the signup and login functions without modifying the case.  You need to force them to the same case and use that consistently throughout your code.

```
string userName = yourEmail.Text.ToLower();

// always register the user using the lcase namne
var userInfo = await parseAPI.signupUser (userName, yourPassword.Text);

// then when logging in, always use the lcase name for consistency
var userInfo = await parseAPI.loginUser (userName, passwordEntry.Text);
```

You could do the same thing with password, but it's pretty unusual to have a password that isn't case sensitive - I wouldn't recommend it.